# Have values for edge driver changed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

We have a framework that has been working for years. When we start Edge (previously IE) we specify unexpectedAlertBehavior:

```
eOp.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "ignore");
...
driver = new EdgeDriver(eOp);
```

this has worked but now we are getting

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal key values seen in w3c capabilities: [unexpectedAlertBehaviour]"
```

same problem if I try upper case:

```
Illegal key values seen in w3c capabilities: [UnexpectedAlertBehaviour]
```

Is this no longer valid?  Edge (and driver) version 9Version 122.0.2365.92).
I am not attaching to IE since this does not need to be run in IE mode.
Java version is java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.332-2.

Is there a new property?

Comment: you might try with promptBehaviorConstant = UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE; eOp.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(promptBehaviorConstant);   (That's what it'd be for ChromeOptions methinks... not sure if EdgeOptions has this?)

Comment: I will try it. I guess we are not allowed to say thank you, so... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unexpectedAlertBehaviour` is deprecated. You need to update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/. You could use [`unhandledPromptBehavior`](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#capabilities) instead.

```
eOp.setCapability("unhandledPromptBehavior", "ignore");
...
driver = new EdgeDriver(eOp);
```